# Reload crashed taskbar in Ubuntu mate

Tags: ubuntu-mate, taskbar

As I have said in the title, I would like to know if there is any way to restart the task bar in Ubuntu MATE. I have had my top and bottom bars crash on me several times, which means that I could do nothing besides shut down and reboot.

Of course, I would much rather just reload the bar and continue with whatever I am doing, if it is possible.

Does anyone know how to do this? I have found similar questions, but only applying to the Unity menu bar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MATE panels are created with `mate-panel` executable, so for reloading them you should execute in terminal `mate-panel --replace &` or  `mate-panel --replace` in *Run Application* launcher (called by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) .

Comment: Thank you @N0rbert, I will test this out to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Very simple and useful, thanks

Comment: I get this: `** (mate-panel:26518): WARNING **: Cannot register the panel shell: The given address is empty` when I try `mate-panel --replace &`